# How to send message from server back to client in C# WebSocket?

Tags: c#, websocket, client-server, tcplistener

I am a junior programmer and it is my first time building a WebSocket application in C#.

I have been following the tutorial from this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server

By sending messages from the client to the server, everything works well. However, I want to have a bidirectional connection, so that the server could send messages back to the client in order to see them in the browser.

I have tried the following method, by adding the following lines to the server code:

```
byte[] tosend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Message received by server");
stream.Write(tosend, 0, tosend.Length);
```

I thought the client would receive this message but unfortunately, it return an undefined error and closes the connection.

Could you explain why this method of sedning messages doesn't work and maybe give me a few suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm...not sure where the "WebSocket" is in that linked example.  I thought WebSocket used _messages_. That code appears to be just using _streams and pure TCP APIs_ making it just ordinary TCP

Comment: Web sockets is a complicated API, and you seem to just be writing naked data to a stream, which is very different. There are inbuilt APIs in .net to handle web socket connections as a server: have you used those?

Comment: (I said API, but I meant protocol)

Comment: I am starting to familiarise with inbuilt APIs in .net. However, I can't seem to find a tutorial that starts from nothing to build a simple client-server WebSocket communication. Could you point me one?